# How to use g++ in terminal in mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, gdb

I've installed Xcode and I can compile .cpp files in Xcode. However, I wanna use g++ in Terminal but command not found: g++ now. 
My OS is Mountain Lion Xcode version is 4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download and install the Command Line Tools for OSX Mountain Lion from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (you'll need a Apple ID which is free to sign up for). This will install GCC (including g++) so you can build direct from Terminal

The exact package currently is Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - September 2012

Description about the package from Apple:

> This package enables UNIX-style development via Terminal by installing command line developer tools, as well as Mac OS X SDK frameworks and headers. Many useful tools are included, such as the Apple LLVM compiler, linker, and Make. If you use Xcode, these tools are also embedded within the Xcode IDE, and can be installed on your system using the Downloads preferences pane within Xcode 4.5.

Comment: You can actually install them directly from Xcode's preferences.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer +1 for the tip. Preferences -> Downloads if anyone is wondering. Also if you don't want to download and install the Command Line then with the latest Xcode (4.5) just preface your commands with `xcrun` (eg. `xcrun g++ test.c`) and it'll use the tools shipped directly with Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you run "g++" with Xcode 4.5 installed, you're picking up llvm-g++-4.2 (based on gcc 4.2.1) -- a provided, but no longer supported compiler on the platform.  I'd strongly recommend using clang++ instead, the actively supported/developed compiler on the platform.

Comment: Yes, the gcc/g++ in XCode is pretty much out of date. Just recently 4.7 and 4.8 have been released and is recommended if you are using the new C++11 standards