# How to use std::bind

Tags: compiler-errors, bind

I'm trying to implement the std::bind in an easy example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a * b;
}
int main()
{
    auto f = bind(multiply, 5, _1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "5 * " << i << " = " << f(i) << endl;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

however, when I compile this is what I get:

```
test.cpp:5: error: ‘placeholders’ is not a namespace-name
test.cpp:5: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘f’ with no type
test.cpp:14: error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:14: error: ‘bind’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:17: error: ‘f’ cannot be used as a function
```

awkward when a given example returns compilation errors o.O

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Which compiler are you using?std::bind was introduced with c++11. Your compiler may not be supporting c++11 or you are not passing the correct options to the compiler

Answer (score 4):

Your code compiles fine as long as `-std=c++11` switch is passed to `gcc`, and with the November CTP compiler release of Visual Studio 2013.

Here's a sample command line compilation for your code:

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp
```

Consult [How to use g++ in terminal in mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652701/how-to-use-g-in-terminal-in-mac) to read about your options - invoking under xcode or directly.

Comment: I work with a mac and I downloaded the c++ compiler in the summer of 2013, so I don't get it why it's not working...

Comment: Summer 2013 is not enough. You need to download the [November 2013 CTP release](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=41151) and select it as the toolset in the Visual Studio's project settings, for your project.